# I want to create an txt file on my desptop, then i want to download the html string of a website and safe it in the txt file

Tags: python, html, download

So here is the code i have already written i dont now if thats the proper way to do it.

```
import os
import requests
import webbrowser
import bs4

print('Enter link:')
siteL = input()

webdoc = requests.get(siteL)
webdoc.raise_for_status()
webhtml = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webdoc.text, 'html.parser')

for chunk in webdoc.iter_content(10000):
    webhtml.write(chunk)

webhtml.close()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) for that like this:

```
urlretrieve("http://www.example.com/somePage.html#someDivWithString", "path/to/textFile.txt")
```

You will have to import `urllib` and append the import to the above request, of course.

**N.B.** Replace `path/to/textFile.txt` with the path to your text file and `#someDivWithString` with the ID of the div containing the string.

Comment: Did the answer help you fixed your issue? If yes, do mark this as the right answer and upvote it Laurids

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests as req
link_to_download=raw_input("Enter Link :")
outfile_name=raw_input("outfilename:")

f=open(outfile_name,"w")

response=req.get(link_to_download)
soup=response.content
soup=bs(soup,"html.parser")
f.write(str(soup.title.string))
f.write("\n")
s=soup.prettify().encode("utf-8")
f.write(str(s))
f.close()
```

Comment: i have modified the code. If it works can you mark the answers ass correct?